# Can we use AWS Data Migration Service for replication from Aurora Serverless as source?

Tags: amazon-web-services, data-migration, aws-dms

My DMS replication instance (which is in same VPC as of Aurora serverless DB instance) is not able to find DB while creating endpoint in DMS. [image]

However, I am able to create a cloud9 instance in same VPC as aurora serverless instance and connect to it from there.

Am I missing something here or it is not possible to use AWS DMS for migrating data from Aurora serverless as source?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Above issue was resolved by explicitly specifying the connection details for aurora serverless cluster (instead of dropdown selection). But the answer to original question of using Aurora serverless DB as source in DMS replication -

1. Yes, if only one time replication is required
2. No, If ongoing replication is required. For ongoing replication, It is required to change the values of binlog_format parameter for source database. Although, Aurora serverless allows changing value for this parameter but it has no impact in actual. Only a few parameters are supported for change which are listed [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/aurora-serverless.how-it-works.html#aurora-serverless.parameter-groups)